# Codeiginiter can not create cookie

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, setcookie

I'm trying to create a cookie with codeigniter for like 2 days -.- (I was to ashame to ask the question before...)

Anyone care to explain me what is wrong with this code:

```
    $websiteUrl = preg_replace("/^[\w]{2,6}:\/\/([\w\d\.\-]+).*$/","$1", base_url());
    $this->load->helper('cookie');

    $cookie = array(
               'name'   => 'rememberMe',
               'value'  => $this->encrypt->encode(serialize($serialize)),
               'expire' => (time() + $this->config->item('remember_me')),
               'domain' => '.'.$websiteUrl,
               'path'   => '/',
               'prefix' => 'chv_',
               'secure' => false,
           );

    set_cookie($cookie);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->input->set_cookie($cookie)
```

(`$this` is CI instance)

- Docs: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html

Make sure `$this->config->item('remember_me')` > 0

---

I was working with CI many times and i was always using native setcookie() function, because i really don't need any framework to set cookie (it's simple operation)... But according to documentation using CI instance and input `CI->input->set_cookie()` should do the job. **Remember NO FRAMEWORK is 100% perfect working...** It's only framework... You can debug step-by-step CI code to see what happens.

*(from comment)*

Comment: Well using the helper, I should not have to do $this-> ... ( I will test if it works in a few moments )..

Comment: I was working with CI many times and i was always using native `setcookie()` function, because i really don't need any framework to set cookie (it's simple operation)... But according to documentation using CI instance and input `CI->input->set_cookie()` should work. Remember NO FRAMEWORK is 100% perfect working... It's only framework... You can debug step-by-step CI code to see what happens.

Comment: Yeah, debuging step by step was what I did to find out that my error came from inserting something in the db... sometimes I hate the logs of codeigniter... anyway thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there is no extra whitespace being loaded before you are running set_cookie that is preventing the cookie header from being sent to the browser. I have spent many an hour tracking down that issue and found i had an extra space at the end of a closing tag somewhere. If you turn E_WARNING on, this should reveal the issue.